# How to reinstall boot loader on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, rsync, boot-loader

I'm planning to use rsync to clone an entire FreeBSD server to another machine, overwriting the files of the existing old FreeBSD OS (minus `/etc/hostid` and a few others)

But that would break the boot process I think? I imagine I would need to reinstall the boot loader after that, but there seems to be a few different flavors of boot loaders (MBR, PMBR, GPT, EFI...)  It appears I'm supposed to use `gpart bootcode` but how do I know which scheme I should use?

The disk looks like this

```
# gpart show
=>       63  140623749  da0  MBR  (67G)
         63  140616882    1  freebsd  [active]  (67G)
  140616945       6867       - free -  (3.4M)

=>        0  140616882  da0s1  BSD  (67G)
          0   16777216      2  freebsd-swap  (8.0G)
   16777216  123839666      1  freebsd-ufs  (59G)
```

Comment: I would install everything from scratch, transferring or preserving only the necessary files. I would copy the installation only when having many machines, exactly the same.

Comment: In your case you have an MBR scheme. Use `gpart list` for detailed info on the partitioning.